# Why the extended advertisement PDUs(ADV_EXT_IND) can not be both scannable and connectable in BLE spec?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I can't figure out why ADV_EXT_IND can not be both scannable and connectable?

Below messages are captured from Bluetooth Core Spec v5.2 (released 12/31/2019) Volume 6, Part B, Section 2.3.1.5 ADV_EVT_IND (page 2875):

> The ADV_EXT_IND PDU uses the Common Extended Advertising Payload 
>   Format described in Section 2.3.4. The PDU may be used in all advertising 
>   events (**except connectable and scannable undirected**) as indicated by the 
>   AdvMode field value. An advertising event using an ADV_EXT_IND PDU is 
>   directed if, and only if, either the TargetA field is present or the AuxPtr field is 
>   present and points to a PDU where the TargetA field is present.

[image: ADV_EXT_IND]

From Section 2.3.4
[image: AdvMode]

Link to Bluetooth Core Specification Download:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/